# Group by day and hour and count - output 0 if none

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

In rails if I do

```
TrackMood.where(mood: "good").group("date_format(created_at, '%Y%m%d %H')").count
```

It produces the sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, date_format(created_at, '%Y%m%d %H') 
AS date_format_created_at_y_m_d_h
FROM `track_moods` 
WHERE `track_moods`.`mood` = 'good' GROUP BY date_format(created_at, '%Y%m%d %H')
```

And I get a hash as an output

```
{"20120524 11"=>10, "20120524 12"=>7, "20120524 13"=>15}
```

I want to get zeros in the hash for the hours where there are no records created.

I've tried creating an array of all the hours I want to check on:

```
times = ((Time.now - 5.days).to_i..Time.now.to_i).to_a.in_groups_of(1.hour)
         .collect(&:first).collect { |t| Time.at(t).strftime('%Y%m%d %H') }
```

Then trying

```
TrackMood.where("mood = 'good' AND date_format(updated_at, '%Y%m%d %H')
IN (:times)", mood: "good", site_id: 2, times: times )
.group("date_format(created_at, '%Y%m%d %H')").count
```

but this still gives me the same hash as before.

So how do I go about adding the zeros into the hash?

I'm using a MYSQL database.

Comment: Why worry about adding zeroes?  Why not assume an implicit zero if the desired hour is not present in the hash?  Saves a lot of memory!

Comment: I want to pass the values to a graph, so need to add the zeros in if they don't exist.  I assumed adding them in at the database layer would be more efficient.

Comment: It's not easy to do in MySQL - requires outer join with a temporary or inline table containing all of the desired hours.  Tasks like this are often easier done in the application.

Comment: Fair enough - I can do it easily in rails.  Thanks for your input.